# Show keyboard shortcuts for buttons on Word

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

Clicking on buttons wastes time and takes me out of my flow (I prefer to compose without needing to look at the screen/keyboard etc). For common functions - e.g. anything that we can do in `markdown` using standard markup - I'd like to look at the Word Ribbon *once*, memorize the shortcut, and then use that shortcut thenceforth.

However it seems the Ribbon buttons do not even display the shortcut!  In particular the pop-up balloon is useless: it just shows *Heading 1* instead of something like *Heading 1 <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>7</kbd>*   So then is there any way to enable the visibility of shortcuts?

[image]

The following article shows how to do exactly this: but the option displayed does not exist [Displaying Shortcut Keys in ScreenTips](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T013238_Displaying_Shortcut_Keys_in_ScreenTips.html)

It says:

> (last updated December 31, 2022)  This tip applies to Word 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016, 2019, Word in Microsoft 365, and 202

The `View` options on my version of `Word` are:

[image]

Note that even shortcuts is a big letdown versus being able to traverse menus to do these things. But that's a discussion for the overall design of `macOS` out of scope.

Comment: Does this help - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2#PickTab=macOS ?

Comment: @Allan  I was aware of that - I am looking for the hover tips to show that info [ more rapidly and conveniently].  The feature is supposedly available given the link I posted, but maybe this is another "macOs is a second class citizen" situation?

Comment: It doesn’t do what you ask in Windows, either.  So, it’s not macOS being treated as the second class citizen.

Comment: @Allan Do you have a Windows machine to see? The link I posted shows the option that is not available here.